# No texture display for 3D models in Google-Earth Pro when using KMZ with networklink to other KMZ (including the model)

Tags: kml, google-earth, collada, kmz

I face a very strange issue in Google-Earth Pro (desktop client) when I try to display a 3D model "indirectly". Let me explain a bit more.

I try to make life easier for our users by creating a KMZ (=zip of [KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut)) containing only networklink (to other KMZ file in a S3 bucket with presigned links).

These KMZs are very simple (mostly polygons) but one is containing a 3D model, in COLLADA format from Google SketchUp 8 (compatible with GE Pro), including textures files (png) beside. The whole pack (KML + collada + textures) is zipped to a KMZ file.

If I use a KMZ pointing to local KMZ files through the networklink flag : no problem at all. But in my case where I use S3 links, all is working but the textures. The 3D model itself is fine otherwise.

Any idea about how GE Pro is parsing / caching networklinked files to solve this issue ? I guess it is a problem of local path since the content of the file is displayed.

Comment: Are the texture files inside the data KMZ, or are they hosted separately S3?  Either way, the first thing I would check is the references from the 3D model to your texture files, and whether they are direct references in the KMZ, or if they are relative references that will flex to properly no matter where the file(s) are hosted.

Comment: Yes, the textures and DAE model are included in the KMZ. The whole package should be downloaded when we display it. The references in the DAE file are relative, and they point directly to the textures files beside (./texture_xx.png).
I tested the KMZ directly in GE (not from another file) : from KMZ file including model, everything is ok ; from networklink to the same KMZ file, the textures are not working.